# Run-time checking that Python function conforms Protocol/Callable type hinting

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a system that dynamically loads user-inputted Python scripts. These scripts have entry point functions that need to conform certain call signatures.

I am defining and documenting the expected call signature using [Callback protocol](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#callback-protocols), as this approach makes documenting the callables Sphinx documentation friendly.

Here is an example definition:

```py
class DecideTradesProtocol(Protocol):
    """A call signature protocol for user's decide_trades() functions."""

    def __call__(self,
            timestamp: pandas.Timestamp,
            universe: Universe,
            state: State,
            position_manager: PositionManager,
            cycle_debug_data: Dict) -> List[TradeExecution]:
            """

        The brain function to decide the trades on each trading strategy cycle.

        - Reads incoming execution state (positions, past trades)

        - Reads the current universe (candles)

        - Decides what to do next

        - Outputs strategy thinking for visualisation and debug messages

        :param timestamp:
            The Pandas timestamp object for this cycle. Matches
            trading_strategy_cycle division.
            Always truncated to the zero seconds and minutes, never a real-time clock.

        :param universe:
            Trading universe that was constructed earlier.

        :param state:
            The current trade execution state.
            Contains current open positions and all previously executed trades.

        :param position_manager:
            Position manager helps to create trade execution instructions to open and close positions.

        :param cycle_debug_data:
            Python dictionary for various debug variables you can read or set, specific to this trade cycle.
            This data is discarded at the end of the trade cycle.

        :return:
            List of trade instructions in the form of :py:class:`TradeExecution` instances.
            The trades can be generated using `position_manager` but strategy could also handcraft its trades.
        """
```

Then the actual dynamically loaded Python script has the function:

```py
def decide_trades(
        timestamp,
        universe,
        state,
        position_manager,
        cycle_debug_data)
```

I want to validate the users do not have errors, like manual input errors, with their scripts and give friendly error messages about those after the script is loaded (not when the script is being called).

How can I check that a run-time function matches the protocol, e.g. by having the same arguments and argument names as defined in a protocol?

Comment: One option: `assert DecideTradesProtocol.__call__.__code__.co_varnames[1:] == decide_trades.__code__.co_varnames`  Note that comparing the variable names isn't the same as comparing the type annotations; it's possible to conform to the protocol while having different names for the positional args, and it's possible to have the same names but  still produce TypeErrors when you try to actually call the function because the types are different.